# Variable in a function (in a class) is only available to that function where it was made (and defined before)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code i made a second ago, to represent what happens in my original one.

```
class commands:
    def command1():
        #some script
        variable = "test string"
    def command2():
        print(variable)
        #some script
commands.command1() #this goes smoothly
commands.command2() #variable is not defined
```

First, i make a function in class commands, called command1. In it, i define a variable. I make a second function in the class commands, called command2. In it, I want to print the variable I made. At last, I execute the first and then the second command, but instead of getting my variable (that has been previously declared), i get nameerror that its not defined. In my original code, i make a little socket control panel, so i can control my second PC with it (just a lil hobby to play like that with Python). In first function i declare the socket variable, and in second function, i want to call it to send bytes to the server, but the second function doesn't see the variable (even after it has been declared before by the first function). Please help. (also, i just began using classes, and I'm too dumb to understand or find the answer to this. Of course, i tried finding, but couldn't. Also, sorry if I suck. I'm kinda noob at python, and i mostly know more of the basic stuff.)
Edit: I want to know **why** does that happen pls.
[image with the output of my original code][1]

Edit: Fixed, I made a global variable outside of the class so i can use it in every function, class, and outside of it. (thats what i needed)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym3LV.png

Comment: Have you read about ```self``` in Python? If not, please do so

Comment: Please have a look at the [official class tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

Comment: That's not how a class is used. Do you want to use the class as a namespace? That's a bad idea.

Comment: im sorry im new and i read but dont understand

Comment: Have you looked at any examples of programmers using `class` in python? Do they look like what you have posted here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you've misunderstood the concept of classes and variables a bit. What you define as a variable in a Python function will not be accessible in another function, even if they are written in the same file. Look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)

You should probably to do something like this:

```
class Commands:
    variable = "test string"
    
    def command1(self):
        print(self.variable)

    def command2(self):
        print(self.variable)

Commands().command1()
Commands().command2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I made a global variable outside of the class so i can use it in every function, class, and outside of it. (thats what i needed)